# The parent of the root directory

Tags: linux

After cd .. at /, why are we still at /?

Example:

> pradeep@pradeep-laptop:/> cd ..
>   pradeep@pradeep-laptop:/>

Is there a specific reason for this behavior?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125972/cd-on-root-folder

Answer (score 14):

The root directory has a '.' and a '..' entry in it, and the inode number for each is the same.  Traditionally, the inode number is 2; it still is on MacOS X, Linux, Solaris.  So, when you do 'cd /; cd ..', you end up at the same location.

In the 1980s, there was a system called Newcastle Connection that treated networked computers as being above the root of your local computer.  Thus, on such a machine, you would type:

```
cd /../othermachine/path/to/interesting/place
```

to change directory to a remote file system.

(You can find the paper via a Google search of 'Newcastle Connection' - the [URL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.62.9459%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=newcastle%20connection&ei=54aHTIGnFYaosAO3tIjaCg&usg=AFQjCNHJg5KjuRrp7G3ftnP39RcHx2TMzQ&sig2=q7Rb70Y7JLQvrqeucdSmrA&cad=rja) is intractable.)

Answer (score 2):

The `cd ..` command takes you up on level in the directory structure.  Since you're already at the highest level, it just leaves you at the root directory.

Comment: The other answer was good from a technical perspective, but this is the common answer I immediately thought of.  I mean, what else would you expect?

Comment: @Chance: "No such file or directory" doesn't come to mind? :)

Comment: @Roger But then there wouldn't be the invariant that every directory has a `..` parent directory within it. Since the system already has to handle directories that are their own parents (consider hard-linking a directory into itself), making the root its own parent requires no new functionality or special rules, so that decision obeys the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Tyler: once upon an æon or so ago (7th Edition Unix), root could run the `link(2)` system call on directories - because there wasn't a `mkdir(2)` system call and therefore the `.` and `..` entries were created by a root-privileged `mkdir` program.  However, I believe that privilege has been removed even from root these days; you cannot hard-link directories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this behavior is described in the POSIX standard for `chroot`:

> The dot-dot entry in the root directory is interpreted to mean the root
>   directory itself. Thus, dot-dot cannot be used to access files outside the
>   subtree rooted at the root directory.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/chroot.html

and more fully under "Pathname resolution":

> What the filename **dot-dot** refers to relative to the root directory is
>   implementation-defined. In Version 7 it refers to the root directory itself;
>   this is the behavior mentioned in POSIX.1-2008. In some networked systems the
>   construction **/../hostname/** is used to refer to the root directory of
>   another host, and POSIX.1 permits this behavior.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html

While it may seem seem more logical to throw an error, this behavior allows all directories to be treated the same rather than having to treat the root directory as a special case.